# Reassign edits from an import in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

We are struggling with reassigning edits in MediaWiki.

We had two wikis, both powered by MediaWiki. We merged one into the other using the export and import functions. All edits from the second wiki were merged into the first one, this went well for the content.

Our problem is: some people didn't have their account created in wiki #1 before we merged the edits from wiki #2, so these changes were imported as made by "imported>Username", instead of "Username".

Some of these people now have an account. Some don't, but may have one in the future. We would like to make it so that edits currently labelled under the "imported>Username" performer, are registered as made by "Username" - at least for those who have an account already.

To do this, we have unsuccessfully tried the following:

- With `reassignEdits.php` script: fails because "imported>Username" is not actually a user in the database
- Prior creation of accounts with `createAndPromote.php`: fails because "imported>Username" is not a valid username, the ">" character being forbidden in page titles
- RenameUser extension: same problem as above, source user is not an actual user
- ReassignEdits extension: we get a database error (MediaWiki RDBMS error) which we don't manage to track in the logs

It seems strange that it's not possible to do this. Is there something we could change in the PHP maintenance scripts that would help us get over this kind of errors?